# Finding table data via Internet Explorer COM

Tags: internet-explorer, com, powershell

I am trying to automate a download of some data from a web application via Powershell/Internet Explorer COM similar to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337896.aspx).
This works fine for normal elements/pull-downs, but how do navigate through tables via the COM object in case I want to click/find out the links inside a table?

Comment: (*) Is there a public access or do you have to be logged in? I'm asking because in case you have to log in, it is really easier to do it with IE automation. If not, there are other ways like `Net.WebClient`. 
(*) Is the data 'hidden' behind standard links only (in html <a ... />, or is it needed to submit some form etc.?

Comment: This is with https plus javascript to download a file. This is why I like to use Internet Explorer instead of WebClient.

Comment: Do the tables have some id or unique class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$tables = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('table'))
# filter out the tables you are not interested in
$tables = filter-tables-somehow $tables
$links = $tables | 
  % { $_.getElementsByTagName('a') } |
  ? { filter-links-somehow $_ }
# and now process the links as you have been doing it so far
```

You need to filter out some tables that contain links that you don't want to download. The same holds for links - I suppose you want 'click' only some links.

For this kind of automation I would recommend to have a look at [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) (or [PowerWatiN](http://huddledmasses.org/using-powershell-and-watin-powerwatin/)). This could save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard DOM that people usually access in javascript. Try $doc.getElementsByTagName('TABLE') to get a list of tables. Use foreach or pipelines to get at the individual tables.